# Passing id in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need help for my assignment. Now i got a homepage (homepage.html) with three categories and each categories have its sublinks. For examples, the 'Campus' category has three sublinks named 'A','B','C'.

The campus has its own page (campus.html) with three sublinks A,B,C inside it. Clicking A will display the content for A,Clicking B will display the content for B and C for C.

Now when I am in the homepage, I need to click on 'B' in the homepage and it will direct me to the campus.html and showing the B details. Anyone can help? Im new to jQuery, had read all the examples from the web but can't fully understand. Please help me.

Comment: Why does this need to be `jquery`, sounds like a simple `HTML` only site?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a **menu** with [`JQuery UI Menu`](http://jqueryui.com/menu/) to have the following structure..

**HTML**: You'll need to replace the hash links with your html pages.

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
   ............
</ul>
```

**Jquery**:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#menu" ).menu();
  });
```

See the [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/fNy8t/) for an example, you can tweak the menu structure as you want it.